# Chronic hiccups

Tags: chest, neck, throat, hiccup-hiccuping

I have been having real troubles lately with something i named off the top of my head as chronic hiccups. My chest, throat, and neck are hurting because of it. Is this something to get seen for or just something that's no big deal?

Comment: Yes, it's something to be seen for. By all means see a doctor.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). You said yourself that the condition is causing you great discomfort, that is, pain - these are always the situations to see a doctor.

Answer (score 1):

To get a proper diagnosis and see if you really suffer from chronic hiccups, you have to see a doctor. 
Chronic hiccups can be a symptom of another disorder, so sometimes treatment is based on treating the underlying condition. There are also medicines that can ease very severe cases of chronic hiccups, but they are not the sort of medication you should be taking on your own. If you need medicines, adequate therapy can be prescribed by your physician - which is another good reason for a visit to the doctor's office.

References:
[Hiccups, Chronic](https://rarediseases.org/rare-diseases/hiccups-chronic/) - National Organization for Rare Disorders